# Proving that for any any $n$ distinct real number the number of multiplications needed to compute their product is $n - 1$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I am studying for one of my exams, and and this question appeared in the practice problems for the exam. I tried proving it but got stuck midway. What I tried was using strong induction to induct on the number of brackets in a given expression. However, I am not quite sure how to build my proof based on this. I was able to do the base case and inductive hypothesis, but when it came to the inductive case, I was unsure how to proceed. Would inducting on the number of brackets be helpful in this scenario?

[image]

Any sort of help will be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Use induction based on how many numbers are used in the expression (i.e. $n$), not on how many brackets there are.

Comment: I am already stuck on the base case $n=1$, LOL! @JaapScherphuis

Comment: Base case is not $n=1$  It's $n=3$.  $(a_1a_2)a_3 = a_1(a_2a_3)$.  That's a given by the associative axiom of multiplication.

Comment: Key:  No matter how you order $a_1.....a_n$ you will alway do it by multiply two result's together (step by step) so there will always be a last two results  $(a_1....a_k)(a_{k+1}....a_n)$.  Example: $a_1a_2a_3a_4$ must have one of the follow last two results $\color{blue}{a_1}\color{red}{(a_2(a_3a_4))}$ or $\color{blue}{a_1}\color{red}{((a_2a_3)a_4)}$or $\color{blue}{(a_1a_2)}\color{red}{(a_3a_4)}$ or $\color{blue}{(a_1(a_2a_3))}\color{red}{a_4}$ or $\color{blue}{((a_1a_2)a_3)}\color{red}{a_4}$.

Comment: What if you see that one of the numbers is $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strong induction.

Suppose we know that any group of $k < n$ terms the product will be the same no matter which order we do the operations in.

So if we have any $(a_1.....a_k)(a_{k+1}.....a_n)$ where $k <n$ then in wont matter which order we do them within parenthesis.

So that mean every way of arranging $n$  terms will have the same result as any other way of arranging them provided the two largest subgroupings are broken into the same to groups of $k$ and $n-k$ terms.

[For example:  $(a_1a_2a_3)(a_4a5a6)$ will be the same value whether $a_1a_2a_3$ is done as $a_1(a_2a_3)$ or as $(a_1a_2)a_3$ and the same for how we arrange $a_4a_5a_6$. And we know that $(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4a_5a_6)$ will be the same no matter how we arrange that $a_3a_4a_5a_6$.  But we currently *DON'T* know if $(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4a_5a_6)$ must be the same as $(a_1a_2a_3)(a_4a5a6)$.]

[That will be the *next* thing we have to show.  That $(a_1.....a_j)(a_{j+1}....a_n) = (a_1.....a_k)(a_{k+1}.....a_n)$ for any $j$ and $k$.  Will prove that with induction.  Basic induction.]

Now as it doesn't matter how we arrange the $a_1...a_k$ or the $a_{k+1}...a_n$ terms we have

$(a_1....a_k)(a_{k+1}....a_n)=$

$(\color{red}{(a_1....a_{k-1})}\color{blue}{a_k})\color{green}{(a_{k+1}....a_n)}$ is a product with three terms so

$(\color{red}{(a_1....a_{k-1})}\color{blue}{a_k})\color{green}{(a_{k+1}....a_n)}=$

$\color{red}{(a_1....a_{k-1})}(\color{blue}{a_k}\color{green}{(a_{k+1}....a_n)})=$

$(a_1....a_{k-1})(a_k.... a_n)=(a_1....a_k)(a_{k+1}....a_n)$.

And likewise $(a_1....a_k)(a_{k+1}....a_n)=$

$(\color{red}{(a_1....a_{k})}(\color{blue}{a_{k+1}}\color{green}{(a_{k+2}....a_n)})$

$(\color{red}{(a_1....a_{k})}\color{blue}{a_{k+1}})\color{green}{(a_{k+2}....a_n)})=$

$(a_1....a_{k+1})(a_{k+2}.... a_n)=(a_1....a_k)(a_{k+1}....a_n)$.

And thus by induction every way of arranging $n$ terms *regardless* of how you split them into two groups will have the same result.